# C90 - C99: register struct

Tags: c, c99, standards, c89

is "register struct" legal? In terms of standards and (separated from standards) in Gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  (No citation, there is simply no prohibition on that.  There is a note assuming that the use of register with arrays is valid, and arrays are far more second class citizen in C that structs).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is legal, however since register is only a hint to the compiler to what it might try,  no implementation actually has to listen to it anyway. It is also easy to make a struct that couldnt be stored within the space allotted in registers.

Once you start to get so close to machine dependant problems their part in standards tends to be merely suggestions since hardware varies such that the same things are not reliably possible at this level in all architectures.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is valid.

`register` as a keyword just doesn't mean that the variable is to be held in a register. (C basically has no concept for this). It simply means *don't take an address of this variable*.

Comment: It's too bad `register` imposes constraint violations, since otherwise it would have been more useful to have the keyword mean "The value of this lvalue will not change between accesses thereto unless its address is taken *between those two accesses*.".  Given something like `register x,y; getCoords(&x,&y);` the compiler would have to store `x` and `y` in memory during the call to `getCoords`, but could cache them in registers afterward.  Useful for optimization, and something a compiler would likely not be able to figure out on its own.  Too bad the Standard would consider that...

Comment: ...a constraint violation.

Comment: @supercat, you really dug out an old one, here. No, as you say such kind of optimizations are better left to the compiler, I think. `register` as it stands really only is a marker for *I don't want this variable to alias, ever*, and can be quite useful in combination with `const` qualification.

Comment: As it presently stands, does the `register` indicate anything that a multi-pass compiler *couldn't easily figure out for itself*?  By contrast, Is there any way a compiler could figure out that it may be safe to register-cache across outside function calls an object whose address has been exposed to the outside world?  Basically, I'd be saying that an object won't be aliased, ever, *except in certain narrow easily-identifiable contexts*.  The directive would serve a purpose much like `restrict`, but for things which are mostly accessed directly rather than via pointers.

Comment: Proper use of such a `register` qualifier, as described, along with `restrict`, would give the compiler the information needed to perform most useful aliasing optimizations even in `-fno-strict-aliasing` mode (along with many that aren't presently possible even with `-fstrict-aliasing`).  BTW, `register` is also presently a constraint violation for global variables, but applying the same semantics there would likewise allow optimizations that are impossible, such as keeping a global `register int foo;` cached in a register across an access to an `int*`.  Is there any present way to allow that?

Comment: Current register is similar to restrict. Removing it from valid code doesn't change the semantics. Adding it can invalidate code, and thus point to a spot that misses some optimization. But an old question like this is probably not the right lieu to discuss this.